# Google Adwords API Segmentation questions

Tags: .net, reporting, google-ads-api

I'm using the adwords api .NET client library to get for example impressions from a list of accounts. I would like to get data using the segmentation 'per hour' from the API. I know it
is possible using the ReportingService but is it also possible using a 'normal' call to the CampaignService 'get' method. I know how selectors work an i use predicates but i don't think it is possible that way.

Anybody any ideas? Below is some example code i use at the moment. This gives me the impressions per day but i would like it per hour of that day.

```
AdWordsUser adWordsUser = <GET USER INFO>
CampaignService campaignService = (CampaignService)adWordsUser.GetService(AdWordsService.v201109_1.CampaignService);
campaignService.RequestHeader.clientCustomerId = <CUSTOMERID>

Selector selector = new Selector();
selector.fields = new string[] { "Id", "Name", "Impressions" };

Predicate predicate = new Predicate();
predicate.field = "Impressions";
predicate.@operator = PredicateOperator.GREATER_THAN;
predicate.values = new string[] { "0" };
selector.predicates = new Predicate[] { predicate };

DateRange dateRange = new DateRange();
dateRange.min = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
dateRange.max = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd");
selector.dateRange = dateRange;

selector.paging = new Paging();
int offset = 0;
int pageSize = 500;

CampaignPage page = new CampaignPage();
selector.paging.startIndex = offset;
selector.paging.numberResults = pageSize;
page = campaignService.get(selector);
```